# Triggering a snackbar when a notification is received via FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, the onMessage function will display an AlertDialog. This functionality works fine.

However, I'd like to show a snackbar instead when the app is in the foreground.

Does anyone have any examples of this?

My current initState:

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
getCurrentUser();
extractMachineIDs(); //IGNORE
getMachineStatus(0); //IGNORE
_fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    showDialog(   // I WANT A SNACKBAR HERE INSTEAD
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: ListTile(
          title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
          subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('DISMISS'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, AlertsNotifications.id);
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of `showDialog`:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Some Text',
    onPressed: () {
      // Some code.
    },
  ),
);
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```